# Can't get https url using urllib, urlib2 or even requests - bunch of erros

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, urllib

I try get https url content but I always got error, I try to get content from few https servers but get same error for all https urls and all is ok for http url

```
import requests
url = "https://pathofexile.com"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.status_code)
```

Any http url I got status_code = 200 and any https url I got error: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'server_hostname'`

I also try urllib and urllib2 with exactly same error, I use Python 2.7.10 on CentOs 6.5
Is there solution for this problem?

Comment: Cant reproduce!

Comment: this code works for me, i use python3

Comment: Seems like it might be a bug in some specific version of python and the way to fix is to either upgrade or downgrade your version.

Answer (score 0):

is there more line of errors occurred before this error? 
did you tried test the code in another operating system?
maybe if you write the complete URL it'll work!!

Answer (score 0):

This is probably Python 2.7.10 bug, I upgrade my Python to 2.7.12 and it's work without any changes